# Angular/Typescript - Getting Warning for Circular dependency

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, circular-dependency

I am facing circular dependency warning in my current project. I need some help to fix this warning issue. I have searched StackOverflow or tech blogs to fix this issue. Unfortunately, I am ending with no proper solution. It will greater if someone helps me with this.

**Below is the project folder structure.**

```
src
 app
  services
   slice
    slice.service.ts
  slices
   home
    help
     help.component.html
     help.component.ts
    home.module.ts
   index.ts
```

**WARNING in Circular dependency detected:**
src\app\slices\home\help\help.component.ts -> src\app\services\slice\slice.service.ts ->
src\app\slices\index.ts -> src\app\slices\home\help\help.component.ts

**help.component.ts**

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

// components
import { BaseSliceComponent } from '@app/components/slice/base-slice.class'

// services
import { SliceService } from '@app/services/slice/slice.service'

// models
import { SliceOptions } from '@app/models/slice/slice.model'

// selectors
import config from './store/victims.selector'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-help',
  templateUrl: './help.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./help.component.scss'],
})
export class HelpComponent extends BaseSliceComponent implements OnInit {
  config: Observable<SliceOptions> = this.store.pipe(select(config))

  constructor(private store: Store<any>, private sliceService: SliceService) {
    super()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

**slice.service.ts**

```
import {
  ComponentRef,
  Injectable,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'

import SliceMap from '@app/slices'

import { SliceNameKeys } from '@app/models/slice/slice.model'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SliceService {
  private sliceStack: ComponentRef<any>[] = []

  private sliceHost!: ViewContainerRef

  constructor(
    private store: Store<any>,
    private router: Router,
  ) {  }

  create(
    name: SliceNameKeys,
    id?: string | undefined,
    shouldClear?: boolean,
    index?: number
  ) {
    id = id ?? name // if no id specified keep name as id

    const slice = SliceMap[name]
  }

}
```

**slices/index.ts**

```
import { SliceNames } from '@app/models/slice/slice.model'

// components
import { AboutUsComponent } from './home/aboutus/aboutus.component'
import { HelpComponent } from './home/help/help.component'

const SliceMap: SliceNames = {
  help: HelpComponent,
  aboutUs: AboutUsComponent
}

export default SliceMap
```

**base-slice.class.ts**

```
export abstract class BaseSliceComponent {
  id = ''
}
```

Comment: can you share BasicSliceComponent.ts ?

Comment: Can you post the content of @app/slices and @app/models/slice/slice.model

Comment: @wlf - @app/slices are nothing but 'index.ts' which comes under app/slices/. Hope this clear now

Comment: @AbhinavKumar -  Added

Comment: you are importing sliceMap in sliceService, than sliceMap importing HelpComponent and than HelpComponent importing sliceService. I guess this is the issue. @krrr25

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Yes, but I need the sliceMap which give all details about the component. Like helpComponent, I have few more components all component details will be stored in sliceMap.

Comment: Why is sliceService imported into help.component.ts? is it used in the template? What is the purpose of sliceService, it looks incomplete, even the create method does not look like its all there.

Comment: @wlf - sliceservice will have some functionality to accomplish, for security reason I didn't share whole code. But the code are fine working as expected. Only I want to fix that circular dependency which occur due to index.ts or ...

Answer (score 2):

There is no right solution or tool that can find circulation dependency automatically in your project.

You just need to carefully check each service and injectable that is not circularly dependent.

Like

**A->B and B->A**

You need to check-in each service dependency as well.